# Reading .raw file in C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am new in C++ in general, and thus, also in file handling in C++.

I need to read a `.raw` file which has `16-bit integers`, and have dimension `512 x 512`.

For that I am using following code:

```
ifstream myData("myData.raw");
short value;                                             
int i = 0;
char buf[sizeof(short)];
while (myData.read(buf,sizeof(buf)))
{
    memcpy(&value, buf, sizeof(value));
    cout << value << " ";
    i++;
}

cout << endl << "Total count: " << i << endl;
```

The value i am getting for `i` is not `512 x 512`. So I guess something is not right.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: What value _are_ you getting?  What is `ls -l myData.raw`?

Comment: Your `myData.raw` is expected to be with size 524288 (512*512*2), but I suspect your file is not with this size...

Comment: Shouldn't it be (512*512*2*2) assuming short ints are 16 bits

Comment: The size is indeed 524288.

Comment: Open it in binary mode.

Comment: like this `ifstream myData("myData.raw", ios::binary);`

Comment: @doug Thank you. It worked. If you can post it as answer, I will accept it.  Also thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default open mode is "text" and some characters will be possibly dropped or treated as end of file. ios::binary stops these alterations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream myData("myData.raw", ios::binary);
    short value;
    int i = 0;
    char buf[sizeof(short)];
    while (myData.read(buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        memcpy(&value, buf, sizeof(value));
        cout << value << " ";
        i++;
    }

    cout << endl << "Total count: " << i << endl;
}
```